# Term/expression for "to spend too much time talking about an issue"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

In the context of a business meeting, the chair of the meeting tells the participants that he doesn't want to "dwell on the tasks that have already been closed".

To my understanding, "dwell on" means to think about something at length. Is there a better word or expression that the chair could have used?

Comment: For anybody to suggest a better word, you'd have to tell us what the chair of the meeting actually meant. Also this question contains no evidence of research.

Comment: The chair meant that he didn't want to spend any extra time discussing things that had already been finalized.

Answer (score 5):

See **belabor**.

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/belabor)

> to explain or work at (something) more than is necessary.
>
> to argue or discuss in excessive detail.

Answer (score 2):

Certain phrases may not be suitable for the setting of a business meeting, but here are some of the ones that come to mind.

The verb "discuss" means to talk about something with a group of people.

The verb "expend" means to spend or use; in this context, the chair would say he did not like *expending unnecessary time*.

Saying something is "excessive" means that it was more than enough to get the job done.

*To **beat a dead horse*** can mean to waste time or energy doing something that is not possible or not needed.

Comment: Hi @Symantra, thanks for your suggestions. I'm familiar with discussing and expending time. What I'm looking for is a short and quick waying of saying this, something likely to be heard in a business setting.

Comment: 'beat a dead horse' is used all the time in meetings.